# Blue Tooth Discover is giving old name if I discover after bluetooth device rename

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, 32feet

I am using 32 feet library to connect and discover Bluetooth devices.
If I rename my bluetooth device name, after that if I try to discover, its giving me old name.

1)Connect to bluetooh device1.
2)Disconnect to bluetooh device1.
3)Rename bluetoothdevice1 to bluetoothdevice2.
4)If I discover now, I am getting bluetoothdevice1, I do second discover again I am getting bluetoothdevice2.

Not sure it is the issue with 32feet or windows.Is it caching somewhere in the system and it is returning it?

Comment: It is correct behaviour for MS drivers. In order to resolve this you have to process some WM_DEVICECHANGE message in your application (Refer to MSDN: Bluetooth and WM_DEVICECHANGE). Bluetooth sends this message to the subscribed applications when device name is resolved. In is the similar to reading empty device name issue.

Comment: Thanks @mike-petrichenko, I downloaded your framework for Demo and when tested with your framework it is working Perfect. I mean even though I change the name of the Bluetooth device, with your Demo application if I discover, it is giving correct blue tooth device name(i mean the new updated name). I assume your framework might be using these WM_DEVICECHANGE  messages. I will try to use them and see if I can make any progress. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @mike-petrichenko
NativeMethods.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface = new NativeMethods.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterface);
deviceInterface.dbcc_size = size;
deviceInterface.dbcc_devicetype = NativeMethods.DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
IntPtr buffer = default(IntPtr);
buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(deviceInterface, buffer, true);
NativeMethods.RegisterDeviceNotification(radiohandle, buffer, NativeMethods.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE | NativeMethods.DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);

Comment: @mike-petrichenko  I registered for the device notification like above, then Do I need to write windows message pump handler to get receive and process the messages?

Comment: You should use DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEHANDLE. But the first step you have to use BluetoothFindFirstRadio() function to get Bluetooth Radio driver object handle and use this handle in RegisterDeviceNotification() function to subscribe to notifications.

Comment: I am not sure if that works with DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE. If yes, then you do not need message pump. If no then you need message pump.

Comment: Thank you @mike-petrichenko  Do  I need to assign any guid for devHandle.dcbh_eventguid ? what is that Guid value.

Comment: IntPtr findhandle = NativeMethods.BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ref bfrp, out handle);
NativeMethods.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEHANDLE devHandle = new NativeMethods.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEHANDLE();
devHandle.dbch_size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(devHandle);
devHandle.dbch_devicetype = NativeMethods.DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE;
IntPtr buffer = default(IntPtr);
buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(devHandle));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(devHandle, buffer, true);
IntPtr testIntPtr = NativeMethods.RegisterDeviceNotification(handle, ref devHandle, 0);